# Prestashop Error, redirected to many times after migrating to another host and domain

Tags: prestashop, migrating

I transferred my prestashop site to another host and domain and now im getting "redirected to many time" error.

This page isn’t working
www.yoursite.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 1):

If you has move from one domain name to another, as first step you need clear cookies in your browser, and clear cache also, then you need update the domain name in the `SEO & URLs tab`, inside the `Advanced parameters`.

If you are getting issued by access to the Back Office, you can change this also directly in your database in the table `ps_shop_url`, you need update `domain` and `domain_ssl`.